# Converting to img tag in xlst

Tags: xslt

This is my xml file:

```
<xml>
<figure>abstract.png</figure>
</xml>
```

This is my xslt code:

```
<xsl:template match="figure">
<img src="{.}" alt=""/>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

But it gives this:

```
<img src="abstract.png" alt=""/>abstract.png
```

instead of just:

```
<img src="abstract.png" alt=""/>
```

How to remove the last abstract.png?

Answer (score 1):

The trailing string `abstract.png` is produced by your instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

If you remove it, you will get the expected result:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aiyndL